# How to know when a fixture needs to be re-caulked?

Tags: caulking

I recently bought my first home, and am trying to be a good homeowner. I know that the bathtub, toilets, and sinks (anything else?) are supposed to be caulked well. I have no idea how long the current caulk has been there.  Nor do I know how to tell if it's still "good" or needs to be redone.

What should I look for to determine when it is time to go through the re-caulking process?

Comment: when it leaks...

Comment: how do you know if it is leaking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd replace the caulk if it begins to crack or shows signs of mold. Old caulk can be perfectly fine as long as it's not cracking and allowing water to penetrate. If there's a lot of movement in the structure, expect to need to replace the caulk more often.